# The GUI uses all my bandwidth and I can't browse anymore or use another application that requires internet connection

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, bandwidth

Per title, the GUI uses all my bandwidth and I can't browse anymore or use another application that requires internet connection. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`monerod` takes a lot of bandwidth during the initial sync. If you're unable to browse or use any applications that require internet connection, you can limit `monerod`'s bandwidth as follows:

1. Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI.
2. Look for the `daemon startup flags` box.
3. Add this line -> `--limit-rate 500`
4. Exit the GUI and make sure to stop the daemon as well.
5. Restart the GUI + daemon.

Step 4 & 5 are needed for the flag from step 3 to take effect. Note that `--limit-rate 500` will limit the bandwidth to 500 kB/s. Note that you can tweak the parameter / flag yourself by adjusting the value.